# Character string with timezone convert to date

Tags: r, date, datetime, strptime

I am trying to convert a vector of dates that I read from a csv file using read.table. These were read as a vector of character strings. I am trying to convert it to a date vector using as_date.

The date vector has elements of the below type

```
dateString
"Wed Dec 11 00:00:00 ICT 2013"
```

On trying to convert using the below command,

```
as.Date(dateString,"%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
```

> ```
> Error in strptime(x, format, tz = "GMT") : 
>   use of %Z for input is not supported
> ```

What would be the right format to use in strptime? or in as.Date?

Comment: Timezone should be removed. You can store it in a separate column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `anytime()` function from the [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) package:

```
R> anytime::anytime("Wed Dec 11 00:00:00 ICT 2013")
[1] "2013-12-11 CST"
R>
```

There is also an `utctime()` variant to not impose your local time, and much.  By now we also had a number of questions here so just search.

And if you want a date, it works the same way:

```
R> anytime::anydate("Wed Dec 11 00:00:00 ICT 2013")
[1] "2013-12-11"
R>
```

Comment: timeseries and timezones, time-etc. are your ground. +1 Deleted my answer.

Comment: @Dirk - Works perfectly. Thank ytou. If i would need to do this for a vector with around 18 million entries (source csv file is really huge), is there any faster way to do this conversion?